# Using external data into custom error-handler (no globals)!

Tags: php, parameters, custom-errors

Is there any easy way to use some variables (declared outside) inside the custom error function?

For example:

```
$a = "something";
$b = 123;

function errhnd($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
  # need $a and $b vars here!
  }

set_error_handler('errhnd');
```

I can do it using globals and not sure is it a good way, is there anything else I can do to pass some data into my custom error-handler function?

Comment: Why don't you just pass it ?

Comment: @Shankar how? that function is called automatically when error/warning/notice occurs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Global`:

```
  # need $a and $b vars here!
  global $a;
  global $b;

  // Use them here!
```

or even shorter:

```
  global $a, $b;
```

Or use `$GLOBALS[]` like this:

```
  echo $GLOBALS['a'];
  echo $GLOBALS['b'];
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

And you can pass them ofcourse like this:

```
function errhnd($a = NULL, $b= NULL, $errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
  # need $a and $b vars here!
  }

set_error_handler($a, $b, 'errhnd');
```

Comment: I mentioned bellow the code, I know how to use globals, that's what I'm doing right now, but I want another way,

Comment: If not set `$a` or `$b`, they will be `NULL`.

Comment: let me try this, looks like what I need just to be sure.

Comment: NO, throws warning "Warning: set_error_handler() expects at most 2 parameters, 3 given in...", according to function's manual it's not possible this way.